# org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException with Selenium Java 3.0.1 Firefox version 51.0.1

Tags: java, maven, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException with selenium java
>   3.0.1 firefox version 51.0.1.

I am trying to use the Gecko driver.

**Here is my code**

```
public class Gecko {
   String driverPath = "/home/hema/Downloads/Softwares";
   WebDriver driver;

   @org.junit.Test
   public void Test() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", driverPath + "/geckodriver.exe");
     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
     capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
     driver.get("http://awsstagewebdriver.doctorinsta.com");
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown(){
    driver.close();
  }
}
```

**Dependices**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: which version of geckodriver you are using?

Answer (score -1):

Please downgrade the firefox version 51.0.1 to 46.0.1.